# Are you allowed to nest a link inside of a link?

Tags: html, css

This may seem pretty basic, are you allowed to put a link inside of a link? See attached image below:

[image]

I'm trying to have the whole grey bar clickable to go somewhere, but if the user clicks the wheel or the move arrow, they are other links.  See my current code:

```
<a href="#" class="sp_mngt_bar">
    <h1><?php echo $v; ?></h1>
    <a href="#" class="t_icons t_icons_settings sp_mngt_settings"></a>
    <a href="#" class="t_icons t_icons_move sp_mngt_move"></a>
</a>
```

Is this a good practice?  Am I doing it wrong? How would you do this?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Rather than that, a block level `<h1>` is certainly misplaced inside an `<a>`.

Comment: @deceze: Not anymore in HTML5.

Comment: what's the point, why not just wrap h1 in link instead of wrapping hole thing in link, just to have 2 other items take on different links

Comment: A why version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal

Comment: A best workaround version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874342/semantically-correct-nested-anchors

Answer (score 94, accepted):

*Straight from the W3C for HTML4:*

### 12.2.2 Nested links are illegal

Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be nested; an A element must not contain any other A elements.

Since the DTD defines the LINK element to be empty, LINK elements may not be nested either.

### HTML 5

And for [HTML5 it is a little different](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-a-element).

You cannot have [Interactive Content](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#interactive-content) inside an A element. **Interactive Content includes anchor tags.**

Comment: Thanks for the links, very informative and direct! FWIW, even though it's invalid, every browser I've tested (Firefox 26, Chrome 34, IE8+) actually allows you to nest link tags without repercussion - no implicit closing tags were inserted. It's kind of a moot point though - I think the UX of having nested links leading to different URLs is so hard to understand it should never be done.

Comment: Just to clarify: HTML5 anchor tags cannot contain anchor tags, even anchor tags that are not interactive content (i.e. anchor tags without the href attribute).

Comment: @Jonz fast-forward a few years – Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 on a Mac adjusts the HTML if an anchor is embedded in another anchor...

Comment: Yeah, this answer is just wrong: the linked HTML 5 very clearly says that an anchor tag cannot have an anchor tag descendent.

Answer (score 87):

To simply answer the question: [No](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882916/are-you-allowed-to-nest-a-link-inside-of-a-link/#9883044).

That being said, here's a pure html/css workaround:

https://codepen.io/pwkip/pen/oGMZjb

```css
.block {
  position:relative;
}

.block .overlay {
  position:absolute;
  left:0; top:0; bottom:0; right:0;
}

.block .inner {
  position:relative;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.block .inner a {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <a class="overlay" href="#overlay-link"></a>
  <div class="inner">
    This entire box is a hyperlink. (Kind of)<br><br><br><br>
    <a href="#inner-link">I'm a W3C compliant hyperlink inside that box</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note for future users: The `.inner` has to always be the element directly above the inner link - no matter how far nested it is relative to `.block`

Comment: I did not need the z-index property

Comment: Searched for a long time, only simple answer to find anywhere thanks a **lot**.

Comment: Is this legal? Is it guaranteed to work?

Answer (score 34):

Wrap your nested link inside an object tag :

```
<a href="#" class="sp_mngt_bar">
    <h1><?php echo $v; ?></h1>
    <object><a href="#" class="t_icons t_icons_settings sp_mngt_settings"></a></object>
    <object><a href="#" class="t_icons t_icons_move sp_mngt_move"></a></object>
</a>
```

Comment: I would suggest to check your performance after you apply this hack. We added it to the app and sometime later discovered that our pagespeed score went down. It turns out that wrapping the links like this was the reason in our case.

Comment: @sasha Can you elaborate? Why? And how did you fix it?

Comment: While this technically works, I noticed some glitchyness when navigating to the different links.

Answer (score 10):

Although I totally agree with the selected answer and yes, you *shouldn't* have Interactive Content inside an A element, sometimes you may need a workaround to this.

Here's an example where you *need* to put an interactive element inside an A tag. That little close button on the top right.

[image: Interactive element in an A tag]

Here's the HTML for this. (It's not the actual build, I made it a bit simpler)

```html
    <a href="#">
        <span class="hide">X</span> <!-- THIS IS THE SMALL 'X' WHICH HIDES THE WHOLE BOX -->
        <img src="images/camera.svg" width="50" alt="Camera" />
        <em>
            Upload a profile picture
            <small>
                Here's the deal. Make your profile look awesome and even get 25 karma for it. We're not kidding.
            </small>
        </em>
        <strong>
            + 25 K
        </strong>
    </a>
```

So, basically we want to hide this box when the user clicks on the 'X'. Otherwise, just it should work like a simple A tag. Here's the jQuery which did the trick.

```js
    $('.hide').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation(); // THIS IS THE KEY PART
    
            // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT, I FADED OUT THE BOX FOR EXAMPLE
            $(this).parent().fadeOut(300);
    });
```

I hope this helps someone with the same problem. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I would restyle it so that it is more like this format:

```
<div class="sp_mngt_bar">
    <h1><a href="#"<?php echo $v; ?></a></h1>
    <a href="#" class="t_icons t_icons_settings sp_mngt_settings"></a>
    <a href="#" class="t_icons t_icons_move sp_mngt_move"></a>
</a>
```

Comment: There should be some content in the `a` elements. Though formally correct, an empty `a` element is bad for accessibility. (I suppose the idea is that they have CSS settings including a background image, but that’s bad for accessibility.)

Comment: Why is having an empty a element bad for accessibility? I often use this to reduce the HTML requests and for Sprites.

Answer (score 4):

Nested links are illegal. To achieve the same behavior as with nested links you can do the following:

Use @mikevoermans HTML format as shown below and bind click event

```html
<div class="sp_mngt_bar">
    <h1><a href="#"<?php echo $v; ?></a></h1>
    <a href="#" class="t_icons t_icons_settings sp_mngt_settings"></a>
    <a href="#" class="t_icons t_icons_move sp_mngt_move"></a> 
</div>
```

Your click event should look like this:

```js
$(".sp_mngt_bar").bind("click", function(e) {   
    var target = $(e.target);
    if(target.has('.t_icons_settings') { //Do something for settings } 
    else if(target.has('.t_icons_move') { //Do something for move }
    else { //Do something for sp_mngt_bar
});
```

Answer (score 1):

While technically not an answer to the question, another workaround is to bind the click event to a `span` or `div`:

```
<a href="outer-link">
  Outer Link
  <span class='inner-link'>Inner Link</span>
</a>

$('.inner-link').click(function (e) {
    // Prevent the click-through to the underlying anchor
    e.stopPropagation();

    // Go to a link
    window.location.href = 'page.html';
    // Or call a javascript method
    doSomething();

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Note that this prevents users from opening the link in a new tab for example.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to position a link absolutely inside of the parent link container:

```
<div style="position: relative">
  <a href="#">
    <h1><a href="#"<?php echo $v; ?></a></h1>
    <div id="placeholder" style="height: 24px">
  </a>
  <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jules answer, just shorter:

```
.parent {
  position:relative;
}

.overlay-link {
  position:absolute;
  inset: 0;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <a class="overlay-link" href="..."/>
    <div class="child">
                    
    </div>
</div>
```