# Make clickable link inside clickable box (ActionLink inside <a href>)

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I am trying to make a whole table row clickable and have done so using javascript. However, this does not let you see the target link in the status bar and also prevents you from opening these links in new tabs.

Therefore, I have been trying the following:

```
<tr>
  <td><a href="#">@Html.ActionLink(...)</a></td>
  <td><a href="#">@Html.ActionLink(...)</a></td>
  <td><a href="#">@Html.ActionLink(...)</a></td>
</tr>
```

Then using display:block; on the anchors to make the full row clickable.

```
tr:hover { 
   background: red; 
}

td a { 
   display: block; 
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 16px; 
}
```

However, I can no longer click the action link, wherever I click on the table row, it takes me to whatever I have in the anchor.

That leads me to my question. How can I make it so that if I click anywhere in the row, it takes me to my anchor, but if I click precisely on the action link, it takes me to where that is set.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot nest a hyperlink inside another hyperlink

Comment: See this answer on nested links http://stackoverflow.com/a/9883044/1398425

Comment: Thanks, thought that might be the case. Any suggestions on a better way of achieving what I am after?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: @ThomasBoby yes I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone has written a plugin for Bootstrap 3 that makes this easy to do. [Jasny Bootstrap](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#rowlink) has "Row Links" which allow you do to the following:

```
<tbody data-link="row" class="rowlink">
<tr>
    <td><a href="#wholerow">First Link</a></td>
    <td>Some text</td><td class="rowlink-skip"><a href="#">Action</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

where the entire row will link to `#wholerow` and the `<a>` tag will link to `#`

Comment: Will this let you open the row links in new tabs and display their target URL?

Comment: I've just tested this out and it doesn't let you open in new tabs or displays the target URL. It only displays it when you highlight the text.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right, was glancing through the repo.

Comment: Thanks for you're help anyway, guess its a minor improvement :)

Comment: You could try something hacky like an invisible tooltip over the entire row? Funnily enough someone requested the same feature in Jasny, but I suspect due to the whole no nested links thing it might not be possible to do it via rowlink https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap/issues/422

Comment: Yeah, I have thought about doing a tooltip, it's not exactly what I want, but I guess it's something. Thanks.