# Why a link can not contain a link

Tags: html

**Why a link can not contain a link?**

Why can not use such a structure?
 What is the rule on the w3c specification?

```
<pre>
  <a href="xxx">
   <a href="yyy">
   </a>
  </a>
</pre>
```

Comment: why you need that structure? what's the use case?

Comment: Please see this answer for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/9883044/480773

Comment: You May also refer http://kizu.ru/en/fun/nested-links/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are you allowed to nest a link inside of a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882916/are-you-allowed-to-nest-a-link-inside-of-a-link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to link yyy to xxx try this:

```
<pre>
  <a href="xxx.com">yyy.com</a>
</pre>
```

Your code will not work because you are not anchoring anything