# Nest a link_to inside of another link_to

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I need to nest an 'a' element inside of another 'a' element like so:

```
<a href="www.example.com" class="so-and-so">
    <span>something</span>
    <a href="www.another.example.com" class="another-link"><i class="an-icon"></a>
</a>
```

However I need to use the rails 'link_to' helpers instead of plain html. But when I try to nest the link_to helper like this:

```
<%= link_to "www.example.com", class: "so-and-so" do %>
    <%= content_tag :span, "something" %>
    <%= link_to "www.another.example.com", class: "another-link" do %>
        <%= content_tag :i, class: "an-icon" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It outputs html more like this:

```
<a ...>
    <span ...>
</a>
<a class="another-link" ...>...</a>
```

Any help would be greatly apreciated. Thank you!

## EDIT

It turns out that rails was outputting the correct html after all, but the browser is not interpreting it correctly. It it possible to have a link inside of a link?

## SOLVED (ISH)

It turns out that nesting `<a>` elements is not valid HTML, so the browser was just trying to "correct" my code. I ended up just placing the a element outside the other one and using CSS to make it look the same.

Comment: Are you sure that's what's being output (in the raw View Source), and not just what the brower's correcting it to? Nested links are not legal HTML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882916/are-you-allowed-to-nest-a-link-inside-of-a-link

Comment: Yeah, I just found that out... Thanks!

Comment: What address should the browser load when you click on the inner `a`?

Comment: The inner `<a>` tag should link to a destroy action on a controller, so it needs to use the `method: :delete` options in link_to.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need the inner `link` tag point at a destroy action on a controller. You can trigger the action by the `click` event of the first link.

```
  $('#first_link').on('click', function() {
          $.ajax({
            type: "DELETE", 
            url: YOUR_SECOND_LINK ,
            data: {id: YOUR_ID },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){...},
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){...}
          })
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using the `<template>` element which will prevent the browser from closing an anchor tag before another one is opened.

```
<%= link_to "www.example.com", class: "so-and-so" do %>
  <%= content_tag :span, "something" %>
  
  <template>
    <%= link_to "www.another.example.com", class: "another-link" do %>
      <%= content_tag :i, class: "an-icon" %>
    <% end %>
  </template>
<% end %>
```

I worked this out because I was refactoring Vue components that had nested anchor tags into `html.erb` files. It is a requirement of each of the individual Vue components that it is wrapped in a `<template>` tag so I copied it over and voila!

Comment: `<template>` was not working in my case, but `<object>` worked...