# Prevent parent <a> tag on clicking inner div class name

Tags: jquery

On clicking `favicon-wrapper` I need to add class `selected`. However the `<a>` tag on top not allowing me to click the favicon. Before it triggers it goes to the "offers/test-global.html" page.

How can I prevent parent the `<a>` tag redirection if the user clicks on `favicon-wrapper`?

```js
$('.favicon-wrapper').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="offers/test-global.html" class="offer-list-item-wrapper">
  <div class="offer-list-item">
    <div class="offer-info">
      <div class="offer-text">
        <h4 class="title">Test
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="d-flex">
            <div class="favicon-wrapper">
              <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1497/1497720.svg" />
            </div>
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: You should not nest `a` inside `a`. This is an HTML issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882916/are-you-allowed-to-nest-a-link-inside-of-a-link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal/18667146

Comment: OK.. i removed nested <a> tag. But still when i click "favicon-wrapper". <a> tag on top trigger first

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are you allowed to nest a link inside of a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882916/are-you-allowed-to-nest-a-link-inside-of-a-link)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/daut_m/uvs2681z/1/

You could maybe use `.stopPropagation()` or `.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `event.preventDefault();` to prevent default events (such as links in your case)

```
$('.favicon-wrapper').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

and then, you can redirect with `window.location = "url"` instead of `a` tags if you want to go to another link.