# Preventing scroll to top in href="#" links

Tags: javascript, html, href, add-on

I'm writing an add-on for a page to prevent `<a href="#">` scrolling to the top when clicked.

I know `href="#!"`, `href="javascript:void(0);"` and during the click event `event.preventDefault()` are all solutions.

As the page is dynamic, I'm considering 'absorbing' all clicks or using a `MutationObserver`. At the moment I've implemented the 1st solution (code below).

I'm wondering if someone could help highlight the up and downsides of each solution to help my decision (or if there is an even better solution / improvement to my code). My concern is how each solution scales as the page becomes more dynamic / has more nodes.

I feel adding a click event for the whole document like I've done should scale the best?

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var hash = false
  for (const el of event.composedPath()) {
    switch (el.hash) {
      case "":
        hash = true
      case undefined:
        continue
    }
    hash = false
    break
  }
  if (hash) event.preventDefault()
})
```

To give some context, this is an html5 game and when busiest, there may be 10000+ `<a>` tags in the document and maybe thousands being added/subtracted at a time. I don't want the user to experience noticeable lag with every click they make or when the page changes due to my add-on.

Comment: It seems to me that you could simplify your code to not include any for loops etc. `href = e.target.getAttribute("href");
      if (href !== null && href[0] == "#") 
        event.preventDefault()
      `

Comment: The target may not necessarily be the a tag itself

Comment: that is why the `!== null` is in there, that covers instances when `href` doesn't exist

Comment: See the below answer. If the target's parent is the `<a href="#">` tag, then your code will miss it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could traverse up the DOM from the clicked element with [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and target a link with the specific value in the `href` attribute.

If the result is not `null` then you use `Event.preventDefault()` to cancel the anchor-scrolling from happening

```js
document.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const link = event.target.closest('a[href="#"]');

  if (link === null) {
    return;
  }

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this works better than what I have. Just wondering, why not `if (link) event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: That too would work. It's just a matter of style, I guess. :)

Comment: Just realised, in the case where there are somehow multiple a tags, I would want it to only check the closest 'a' tag (but that's just a minor edit). Suggested edit

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean with *multiple a tags*? Though your edit might better suit your needs, it doesn't answer the title of your question; **Preventing scroll to top in href=“#” links**.

Comment: If you clicked on `<a href="#"><a href="#some link"></a></a>` then your original code would prevent #some link from opening?

Comment: I guess nested anchor tags shouldn't occur, but I believe when they do, only the inner most one is interacted with.

Comment: No it wouldn't. It specifically targets the link with a `href="#"` value. Nesting `<a>` tags [is not allowed in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882916/are-you-allowed-to-nest-a-link-inside-of-a-link#:~:text=12.2.2%20Nested%20links%20are,may%20not%20be%20nested%20either.). So that *should* never happen.