# a link within a link - how to notice an inner click

Tags: onclick

I have code that goes something like this:

```
<a href="" onclick=count() >
<div>
// user content goes here inside
// the div, including links
<a href="" onclick=oops() > </a>
</div>
<a>
```

It paints a clickable banner on top of the screen.

The banner, can have user content inside it, including links, as shown.

What I would like, is to be able to count the clicks "anywhere inside the div", including if the user clicks on the inner link. But the inner link still has to work, so I'd like to notice the click and then somehow pass it up to the upper handler so it counts the same as it would anywhere else inside the div. Can I do that? Can I pass the inner onclick() event to the upper handler, and "then" have it come back down and use the default behavior? An inner click can be trapped with an onclick() and so can the upper one, but if done this way as shown, the inner click will only call the inner handler (and there's duplication of code and it gets a little hairy inside the Java). Can I call the upper handler directly from within the lower handler, is that a safe thing to do? And if so, how do I get it to resume the default behavior afterwards? Or, can I somehow cause the lower handler to trigger an event that notifies the upper handler? What is the best way to do this?

Are there any threading issues with calling a handler directly from within another handler? Anything I should be aware of?

Comment: Having nested links [is a bad idea in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882916/are-you-allowed-to-nest-a-link-inside-of-a-link).  You can handle a click event in the outer element without making that element a link.  Any visible element is "clickable".